# calculate sum of values from a file per name in Shell

Tags: shell

I have a file like this :

```
iphonevisitor -> 125
ipadvisitor -> 200
iphonemember -> 120
ipadmember -> 100
macvisitor -> 230
```

And I want to calculate the sum by *iphone/ipad/mac*, and output it like this :

```
A245 B300 C230
```

A stands for iphone, B for ipad, C for mac.

How should I do this using Shell script?

Comment: this is quite basic, so it would be good to show some of your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filepath"
A=($(grep -o "iphone.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3))
B=($(grep -o "ipad.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3))
C=($(grep -o "mac.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3))
for i in ${A[@]};do ((Asum+=i));done
for i in ${B[@]};do ((Bsum+=i));done
for i in ${C[@]};do ((Csum+=i));done
echo "A$Asum B$Bsum C$Csum"
```

Output:

```
A245 B300 C230
```

A, B, C are arrays which hold the values taken from the third field (assumed space delimited, using `cut`) of each matched string (using `grep`) in the file.

Or:

```
file="filepath"
A=$(grep -o "iphone.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3|paste -s -d+|bc)
B=$(grep -o "ipad.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3|paste -s -d+|bc)
C=$(grep -o "mac.*" "$file" |cut -d" " -f3|paste -s -d+|bc)
echo "A$A B$B C$C"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an associative table to match names with the output characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filepath"

declare -A items

items[A]=iphone
items[B]=ipad
items[C]=mac

for i in "${!items[@]}";
do:
   sum=$(cat $file |grep "${items[$i]}" | cut -d ">" -f2| paste -s -d+ |bc);
   echo -n  "$i$sum "
done
echo
```

finally use echo -n to display sums in the same line.

Comment: `cat file grep` useless use of `cat`. `grep "pattern" file` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of work, `awk` is better, if you have `awk` you can make a try

**Input**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file
iphonevisitor -> 125
ipadvisitor -> 200
iphonemember -> 120
ipadmember -> 100
macvisitor -> 230
```

**Awk script**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.awk
BEGIN{
    Array["A"] = "iphone.*"
    Array["B"] = "ipad.*"
    Array["C"] = "mac.*"
}
{
    f=""
    for(i in Array)
    { 
        if($1 ~ Array[i])
        {   f = i
            break
        }
    }
}
f{
    SUM[f]+=$NF
}
END{
    for(i in Array)
        str = sprintf("%s%s%s",(str?str" ":""),i,SUM[i])
    print str
}
```

**Execution**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -f test.awk file
A245 B300 C230
```